# How prove this $\sum_{k=0}^{l}\frac{(2l-2k)!(2k)!}{2^{2l}(k!)^2[(l-k)!]^2}\sin{(l-2k)\theta}=0$

Tags: calculus

show that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{l}\dfrac{(2l-2k)!(2k)!}{2^{2l}(k!)^2[(l-k)!]^2}\sin{(l-2k)\theta}=0$$

My try
note
$$(2l-2k)!(2k)!=2^l(l-k)!k!$$so
$$\sum_{k=0}^{l}\dfrac{(2l-2k)!(2k)!}{2^{2l}(k!)^2[(l-k)!]^2}\sin{(l-2k)\theta}=\sum_{k=0}^{l}\dfrac{1}{2^lk!(l-k)!}\sin{(l-2k)\theta}=\dfrac{1}{2^ll!}\sum_{k=0}^{l}\binom{l}{k}\sin{(l-2k)\theta}$$
then I can't,Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After change of index of summation $k\to l-k$ you sum changes the sign, but it shouldn't because this is just change of index of summation. Therefore your sum is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula
$$\sin(a-b)=\sin a  \cos b -\cos a \sin b $$
and Leibniz Formula for Derivative of Product